# Encountered FAILED_BUILD_TASKS && DEPENDENCY_COMPATIBILITY_ISSUES while builidng a Dart web application

Tags: dart, web-applications, dart-packages, dart-devtools

This is the `pubspec.yaml` file for the Dart web application:

```yaml
name: coin_game
description: An absolute bare-bones web app.
version: 1.0.0
# repository: https://github.com/my_org/my_repo

environment:
  sdk: ^3.1.3

# Add regular dependencies here.
dependencies:
  # path: ^1.8.0
  webdev: ^3.0.7+1

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.4.0
  build_web_compilers: ^4.0.0
  lints: ^2.0.0
  build_daemon: ^4.0.0
```

And this is the error I am getting after `dart run webdev serve`:

```
Failed to build webdev:webdev:
../../../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dds-2.7.10/lib/src/devtools/handler.dart:111:28: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
    return ServerApi.handle(request);
                           ^
../../../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/devtools_shared-2.26.1/lib/src/server/server_api.dart:33:35: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static FutureOr<shelf.Response> handle(
                                  ^^^^^^
Failed to build webdev:webdev:
../../../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dds-2.7.10/lib/src/devtools/handler.dart:111:28: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
    return ServerApi.handle(request);
                           ^
../../../../../../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/devtools_shared-2.26.1/lib/src/server/server_api.dart:33:35: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static FutureOr<shelf.Response> handle(
```

My research led me to a dependencies incompatibility issues among the `webdev`, `build_daemon`, `build_runner` Dart packages. I tried to downgrade and match compatible dependencies and expected the dependency issues will be resolved, however, the error persisted and the build still fails